# how to request data from our spring boot micro-service to external server for a given id's?

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Currently I have created 2 microservices and and getting the data from one service to another using RestTemplate.

Microservice -1:

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class StringDataController {

List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();


@RequestMapping(value = "/securities/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<String> sendStringData(){

    stringList.add("12345");
    stringList.add("23435");
    stringList.add("23436");
    return stringList;
}

}
```

Microservice-2:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExternalRequestController {

@Value ("${sampleMS1.uri}")
String sampleMS1URI;

@RequestMapping(value="/listdata", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void receiveStringFromAnotherMS(){
    List<String> list = null;

    list = new RestTemplate().getForObject(sampleMS1URI,List.class);

    System.out.println(list.toString());
    System.out.println("-->"+list);
}
}
```

Now, I have to send the List(String)(list of ID's) data to some external server and response should get Map(K,V) ==> key as a String and Value as a Double.

Note: The external server is not handling by us, so we can only request the data with List of id's and then they should sending the response with price data of specific id's.

Can anyone suggest me a way to do it ?

I am new to Spring & Spring boot. 
Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: Hi Wim, I am not sure how I can request to external server with the list of id's. I have googled it and stackoverflow also I have searched but I didn't find anything related to my query. whatever results I have found is related to communication between 2 micro-services.

Comment: May be I am still at a beginner level to understand it.

Comment: Do you know how you can talk to that external server? Do you need to send JSON? And why are you showing 2 microservices here? Is one of the 2 the external one?

Comment: Hi Wim, I think we can talk to the external server using RestTemplate only but I want to send List of id's data with request and response should give me some data w.r.t list of id's. Here 1st microservice is sending  list of id's data to 2nd microservice and 2nd microservice should send those list of id's to external server with the request as told above and response should handle by 2nd microservice.

Comment: Any format is fine as long as we are sending and receiving the data.

Comment: the API documentation for the external API should mention how you can send the list to them it can be in the body or in a file that you should get answers from who ever owns the external API. it cannot be something that you just write.

Comment: +1 to Grinish. If you have an authority to raise your requests to the external server team, then it's okay to send a small list of Ids as GET query paramters. Anything above 3 should be sent as a POST request with the body being the list of Ids. The server may process it and return the mapped results to you.